# does react support IEMobile10 touch event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ie-mobile

I had bind touch events like this:

language: lang-js:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.props.style} onTouchStart={this.touchStartHandler.bind(this)} ref="layer"
                 onTouchMove={this.touchMoveHandler.bind(this)}
                 onTouchEnd={this.touchEndHandler.bind(this)}>
                {this.props.content}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

it does't work on `IEMobile10`, I found `swiper.js` bind `MSPointerDown` instead `touchstart`. should I bind `MSPoint` events in `componentDidMount` function?

Answer (score 0):

Touch Events are in Development Mode in IE10.

Use MSPointerEvents instead of touchEvents.

Eg:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.props.style} MSPointerDown={this.touchStartHandler.bind(this)} ref="layer"
                 MSPointerMove={this.touchMoveHandler.bind(this)}
                 MSPointerUp={this.touchEndHandler.bind(this)}>
                {this.props.content}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

For more info go through link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673557.aspx